# With PHP, trying to select a specific query from a MySQL database gives me everything instead

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM question ORDER BY id';
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        $sql2 = 'SELECT id FROM answer WHERE question_id = ' . $row['id'];
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2) {
            $answers[] = array('ID' => $row2['id']);
        }
        $question[] = array('ID'=>$row['id'],
                            'answers' => $answers);
    }
    print_r($question);
```

With $sql2, when I run it, it gives me every id in question_id, instead of choosing where it is equal to $row['id']. Any idea on how this is happening or what's going on? I'm stumped.

Also, question has a unique id, and question_id is a foreign key in answer which maps to question's id. Answer has unique id values as well.

Comment: Hi Jesse, edit your question and add your table definitions, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$answers = array();
foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2) {
    $answers[] = array('ID' => $row2['id']);
}
```

---

Unrelated, but this is a great use case for prepared statements.  Your queries should also be parameterized for sanitation -- yes, even in this case.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT...";
$sql2 = "SELECT id FROM answer WHERE question_id = ?";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
    foreach ($stmt2->execute($row['id']) as $row2) {
```

Comment: Thank you! It was because I hadn't initialized the array answers?

Comment: @JesseSamson you should initialize it, but it does get initialized automatically each time.  The problem is you didn't *clear* it

Comment: No offense, it's a great solution but I think it's still a mess. A bit more effort in the SQL would result in a better (and faster...) code. IMHO of course, and again, not to offend anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You select all and every id from question table, then all and every answer to the questions. Is this really what you want? if yes, I'd recommend doing this instead:

```
SELECT ASW.id AS 'AnswerID' FROM answer AS ASW
RIGHT OUTER JOIN question AS QNA
ON ASW.question_id=QNA.id
ORDER BY QNA.id
```

So I'd optimize the SQL a bit, instead of building nested foreach statements.
Or if you have a different goal (e.g. list all answered questions) give more details about your table structure and what exactly you'd like to do as this particular issue most probably can be sorted out by a single SQL Statement (EDIT: instead of nested 'for').
I'd also recommend using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) as an easy way to generate a fancy table from the resultset ;)

Answer (score -1):

If your $row['id'] is not a number, it should be quoted in the WHERE clause. Preferably single quoted, although a lot of database systems also accept double quotes.

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT id FROM answer WHERE question_id = '" . $row['id']' . "'";
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Please don't link folks to w3schools. The site is full of outdated and inaccurate practices, and is a certificate mill. Consider linking to the mysql docs instead.